# ModelMapper how to use when condition

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper in Strict mode

```
public class Student {
    private String fullName;
    private Address address ;
}

public class StudentDto {
    private String fullName;
    private String street;
    private String city;
}

public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
}
```

map(source: Student to destination :StudentDto)

in order to escape mapping when address is null i set below condition

```
Condition<Student, StudentDto> conditionAddressIsNull = new Condition<Student, StudentDto>() {
    public boolean applies(MappingContext<Student, StudentDto> context) {
        return context.getSource().getAddress() == null;
    }
};

PropertyMap<Student, StudentDto> propertryMapToStudentDto = new PropertyMap<Student, StudentDto>() {
    protected void configure() {
        when(conditionAddressIsNull).map(source).setStreet(null);
        when(conditionAddressIsNull).map(source).setCity(null);
    }
};
```

the problem is : that i obtain street and city equal to null even when address is not null
how to fix that using STRICT mapping

Answer (score 1):

You should `when(**conditionAddressIsNotNull**)` instead of `when(**conditionAddressIsNull**)`.

`when(condition).map()` means: when condition=true, we map; otherwise, we skip.

I suggest you can try

```
PropertyMap<Student, StudentDto> propertryMapToStudentDto = new PropertyMap<Student, StudentDto>() {
    protected void configure() {
        when(conditionAddressIsNotNull).map().setStreet(source.getAddress().geStreet());
        when(conditionAddressIsNotNull).map().setCity(source.getAddress().getCity());
    }
};
```